# Parameter Manager: Set default value for parameter but still allow it to be edited in email properties

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, parameters, email-studio, web-analytics-connector

We use the following WAC string (I put in line breaks so its easier to read):

```
utm_source=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%​
&utm_medium=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%​
&utm_campaign=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%​
&gid=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%​
```

For the fourth parameter, "gid", I want to set a default value for it so that it is pre-populated when building a new email, but I also want this parameter to remain editable by the user for any given email.

Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds interesting ;) Until now i only know of editable fields and static fields (which you cannot change). Thats a typical question for our mighty Gortonington, Adam Spriggs, Lukas Lunow, Jonas Lamberty, ZuzannaMJ or Cameron Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference AMPScript variables in Parameter Manager.
It all comes down to using templates as intended.

If the AMPScript is part of a (or all) predefined template(s), you can leave it outside of content editors' reach.
This is also a good place to define the variable if you want something "prefilled" (a fallback value).

Then, optionally, when building the email your content creators can use a content block in which they can override the fallback value with a simple SET statement.

```
%%[
SET @myID = "IWantItToBeDifferent"
]%%
```

If you want to get really fancy, then build them a Custom Content Block where they do not have to deal with the *complexities of AMPScript* but get a nice UI.

Then, you reference your variable in Parameter Manager.
The following is a valid entry in Parameter Manager that leverages both Personalization Strings and AMPScript vars.

```
&sfmc_sub=%%SubscriberID%%
&l=%%List_%%
​&u=%%JobURLID%%​
&mid=%%MemberID%%​
&jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%
​&myID=%%=v(@myId)=%%
/*...*/
```

I actually barely use the "additional parameters" any longer.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. That looks like a good way to implement it. Parameters aren't listed in the ampscript order of operations docs, but I assume you've done this before and it works?

Comment: I'd be in big trouble right now in multiple projects if it didn't. :) This was something that already used to work before Parameter Manager, we tested this right at the release of the feature and nothing has changed. True about order of operations, it's not listed, but we can deduce logically that this happens after parsing of HTML and text, as Parameter Manager needs to understand what the links are to add parameters to it, nevermind AMPScript. + personalization strings are used, too. So definitely, AMPScript must have been evaluated before parameters are added to links - and yes, it works.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll give it a go. Thanks